# What am I doing wrong with NSURLSession that's not allowing me to POST to this API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsurlrequest, nsurlsession

I made a quick test project and through this in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.diffbot.com/api/batch"];


NSString *batchJSON = @"[{\"method\":\"GET\",\"relative_url\":\"/api/article?token=...&url=http://www.macrumors.com/2014/01/12/your-verse-ipad-ad/\"}]";
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"token": @"...",
                             @"batch": batchJSON};

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSError *error;
NSData *parameterData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:kNilOptions error:&error];

request.HTTPBody = parameterData;

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *dataResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", dataResponse);
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

I'm trying to POST to [this API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER4Xg.png) which is relatively simple and I can do fine with the example curl statement in that link, but not with the new `NSURLSession` from iOS 7.

I get this error:

> {"error":"Not authorized API token.","errorCode":401}

Which is definitely wrong as I'm copy and pasting the API key I log in with.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your token is correct, contact www.diffbot.com support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem.
The solution that worked for me:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSMutableString *requestString = [NSMutableString string];
[params enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
   [requestString appendFormat:@"%@=%@&", key, 
}];

[request setHTTPBody:[requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Instead of:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSError *error;
NSData *parameterData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:kNilOptions error:&error];

request.HTTPBody = parameterData;
```

Comment: So what changed that made this work? Was it that you were passing in options:kNilOptions to the NSJSONSerialization?

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks correct. One thing to try is to ad the token as part of the url:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.diffbot.com/api/batch?token=...."].  If that does not work, then I agree with  Johnykutty.